JAX-WS interceptor is not being triggerd
The problem is that after adding JAX-WS to my project, specifically to the file that will be generated, I tested the generated file, but nothing related to the interceptor appeared. It seems like I didn’t add it at all, as no issues were shown, and the interceptor doesn’t work.

here is the generated file which it suppose it has the interceptor
package Services;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.jws.*;
import javax.xml.ws.*;
import javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding;
@HandlerChain(file = "C:/WEBLOGIC/wsbank/TPS/WEB-INF/src/Services/handler.xml")
@WebService(serviceName = "Virement")
public class Virement {

    @Resource
    private WebServiceContext wsCtx;

    @WebMethod
    public String WS43(
        @WebParam(name = "NumeroDocument") Long numeroDocument,
        @WebParam(name = "TypeDocument") Long typeDocument,
        @WebParam(name = "RIBBeneficiaire") String ribBeneficiaire,
        @WebParam(name = "Description") String description,
        @WebParam(name = "RIBDonneurOrdre") String ribDonneurOrdre,
        @WebParam(name = "Devise") String devise,
        @WebParam(name = "Montant") Long montant
    ) {
        WS43ImplGen ws43ImplGen = new WS43ImplGen();
        //return ws43ImplGen.Execute_WS43(
           // numeroDocument, typeDocument, ribBeneficiaire, description,
           // ribDonneurOrdre, devise, montant, wsCtxr
        return "test";
       
    }
}

here is the handler chain xml file
<handler-chain xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
    <handler>
        <handler-class>Services.ParameterValidationHandler</handler-class>
    </handler>
</handler-chain>

here is the code logic of the interceptor
package Services;

import java.util.Collections;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.Handler;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPHeader;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPBody;
import java.util.Set;

public class ParameterValidationHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {



    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        System.out.println("done");
        Boolean isOutbound = (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);

        if (isOutbound) {
            System.out.println("Outbound message - Skipping validation.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Inbound message - Validating parameters...");

            // Get the SOAP message
            SOAPMessage message = context.getMessage();
            try {
                SOAPHeader header = message.getSOAPHeader();
                SOAPBody body = message.getSOAPBody();

                // Example of accessing the SOAP message parts, you can validate parameters here
                System.out.println("SOAP Header: " + header);
                System.out.println("SOAP Body: " + body);

                // Add your parameter validation logic here
                // For example, checking certain elements in the body
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // Return true to continue processing, false to block the message
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        System.out.println("Handling SOAP fault...");
        return true;  // You can handle faults here if necessary
    }

    @Override
    public void close(MessageContext context) {
        // Cleanup if needed
    }

    @Override
    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        // TODO Implement this method
        return Collections.emptySet();
    }
}

So here’s the problem, i need your help guys, because I’m going insane and thanks in advance for your help !

still looking for solution :/
